# How to make Visual Studio take automatic actions on check-in?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I'd like Visual Studio 2008 to do a get latest on the solution when I'm checking in, compile the code, run my tests, and if any of these fail, abort check-in.

Is it possible to do it, and how?

edit: We are using  TFS for source control and nunit for testing.

Comment: What source control are you using? Source safe? TFS? Subversion?

Comment: We are using TFS for source control and nunit for testing.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but have you checked Cruise Control for .NET? it's very good for continuous integration, but I don't think you can set it up to revert if the checked in code broke the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio offers a customizable platform, so you can make plug-ins etc.  which handles whatever additional stuff you want to do as part of your check in.

Have a look at the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx) and the [Team Foundation SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx).